# Can permanency be dispelled when cast on a target other than yourself

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e

The description of the spell permanency reads as follows. (Emphasis mine)

> This spell makes the duration of certain other spells permanent. You
>   first cast the desired spell and then follow it with the permanency
>   spell. Depending on the spell, you must be of a minimum caster level
>   and must expend a specific gp value of diamond dust as a material
>   component. You can make the following spells permanent in regard to
>   yourself. You cannot cast these spells on other creatures. **This
>   application of permanency can be dispelled only by a caster of higher
>   level than you were when you cast the spell.**

The way I interpret this is that permanency can only be dispelled if you cast it on yourself with an applicable spell. However I frequently misinterpret these things and it doesn’t really make sense so I thought I’d ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Permanency cast on others can be dispelled as normal

Per the rest of the spell description:

> Spells cast on other targets are vulnerable to dispel magic as normal.